# Why does COIN-OR CBC Solver have both Continuous Solution Unbounded and Dual Infeasible exit statuses?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, online-resources, operations-research

I am working with COIN-OR CBC solver. I understand that Primal unbounded is dual infeasible. After seeing the exit statuses for CBC Solver, I came to know that both these conditions have their own respective exit statuses in the solver. Why is it so and under what circumstance will I get a dual infeasible status?

[This](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc/browser/stable/2.9/Cbc/src/CbcModel.cpp#L6967) is the source where it is defined

Answer (score 1):

If the primal is unbounded, the dual is infeasible. The converse is not necessarily true. Take the following linear optimization problem:

$\begin{align}
\max \{ x_1 : x_2 \leq 1, -x_2 \leq -2, x \geq 0 \}
\end{align}$

This problem is clearly infeasible. The dual is:

$\begin{align}
\min \{ y_1 - 2 y_2 : 0 y_1 + 0 y_2 \geq 1, y_1-y_2 \geq 0, y \geq 0 \}
\end{align}$

which is also infeasible. So, the dual can be infeasible while the primal is not unbounded.

Comment: But in this case, the solver will give primal infeasible exitflag . I am curious to know when the solver will give the dual infeasible exitflag.

Comment: If you look at the source code that the author links to, there are no such exit flags. There are merely functions isContinuousUnbounded and isProvenDualInfeasible, as well as isProvenPrimalInfeasible.The [actual exit codes](http://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/CoinAll/_cbc_message_8hpp-source.html) include CBC_INFEAS and CBC_UNBOUNDED.